# Can $\frac{d^k}{dx^k} e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$ be written in terms of Hermite polynomials?

Tags: hermite-polynomials

We know that  $\frac{d^k}{dx^k} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ can be written in terms of Hermite polynomials as
\begin{align}
\frac{d^k}{x^k} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}= (-1)^k e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}  H_{e_k}(x)
\end{align}

It appears that in this case, we have to use complex values that is
\begin{align}
\frac{d^k}{dx^k} e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}= (-1)^k e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}  H_{e_k}(ix)
\end{align}

My questions: Is this a correct way to go about this? Also, are $H_{e_k}(ix)$ well defined?

Answer (score 2):

$e^{x^2/2} = e^{-y^2/2}$ where $y = ix$.  You should get
$$ \dfrac{d^k}{dx^k} e^{x^2/2} = (-i)^k e^{x^2/2} H_k(ix)$$
(for the "probabilists" Hermite polynomials: physicists would not have the "$/2$").